# Difference in runtime speed assembly vs. C/C++ on an Arduino

Tags: c++, c, assembly, arduino

I have heard that writing an Arduino application in assembly enables the program to be real-time, and that writing the application in C or C++ makes the program slower than that.

If this is true it would mean that for different types of Arduino applications (high speed ones vs. non speed-critical ones) different programming languages should be used.

I am really wondering if that statement is true when the C/C++ code is compiled efficiently.

Comment: This isn't exactly specific to arduino.

Comment: And just what is a "sketch"?

Comment: @Lundin "sketch" is Arduino-speak for a program. Don't know why they felt the need to invent a new term, but they did

Comment: Okay. Maybe Arduino programs end up far more laughable than the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very general question about all of programming, it's not at all specific to the Arduino.

What makes it perhaps pop up a bit more often is that the performance of the basic Arduino is kind of limited, and that it's an embedded platform where low-level operations are very common.

Sometimes you can express such an operation more efficiently in assembler, by using the processor's capabilities more directly, than you can in higher-level languages such as the typical C++.

It's quite common for Arduino libraries to contain assembler code, to make high-performance functionality available for use from C++ more easily.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, assembler will always be more efficient than any compiled language in terms of execution time, just because of the nature of what a compiled language does.  The compiled program, by contrast, will usually be less "fragile" than the assembler, because the higher level language tends to have more error prevention and trapping features as well as data management (some of which are optimized out of the final code, like type checking, and some of which remain in place, like array management).

My reading suggests that Forth is the closest you can get to assembly in terms of execution speed, approaching half the speed of assembler.  In terms of reasonably well known languages that are fairly conventional in structure, C is one of the most efficient and best optimized, so if you're not comfortable in Arduino assembler, C is probably the best choice -- but it'll always be slower than assembler.

Comment: My professor told me, that what you describe was the case in the past. Nowadays c compiler matured that much, that you need to be a real expert in assembly to outperform the assembly output of c compiler.

Comment: @Blechdose That is not so much because of the assembler language VS C language, but rather because compilers optimize code and discard superfluous operations. When writing assembler, nobody else will optimize the code for you.

Comment: @Ludin That is exactly what Blechdose are saying. Due to the high optimization of compilers they will often (nearly always) produce better code than a normal person can do using assembler. That has not always been the case but today for standard platforms it is very seldom that you can beat a c-compiler with your own assembler code. Just use the correct compiler flags and you are good.

Answer (score -1):

This is generally true for all systems: writing in Assembly can be faster. This has mainly to do with the fact that higher languages have an overhead, which makes them safer and more versatile but at the cost of some speed. Normally compiler can make code efficient during compilation, but I suppose that the Arduino doesn't have such features at the time being, or they are not advanced enough.